# Creating a PHP class to handle db connection but getting error

Tags: php, class

I've created (with help) a class in PHP for connecting to and selecting info from a database. Here's the code:

```
<?php

  /* this script is for creating a class to connect to the database */

  include "includes/config.php";

  class database {
    protected static $connection; // variable to hold the mysqli connection


    protected function connect(){
      if (!isset(self::$connection)){
        self::$connection = new mysqli(SERVER_NAME, USERNAME, PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
      }
      if (self::$connection === false){ //in case connection failed return false
        return false;
      }
      else {
        return self::$connection; // returns the connection 
      }
    }


    protected function query($query){ // public function to take a sql query
      $connection = $this->connect(); // calls the connect function to create a connection to the database
      $result = $connection->query($query); // puts the query into the result variable
      return $result; //returns the result
    }


    public function select($query){
      $rows = new array();
      $result = $this->query($query);
      if($result === false){
        return false;
      }
      while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        $rows[] = $row;
      }
      return $rows;
    }


    public function error(){
      $connection = this->connect();
      return $connection->error;
    }
  }

?>
```

The error occurs on the line just before the `select` function which strangely has no code, but that's what the error says. Here is the exact error.

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'array' (T_ARRAY) in C:\wamp64\www\final\includes\connect.php on line 31

Can anyone spot the error?

Answer (score 0):

- there's an syntax error on function `select($query)`:
  `$rows = array();` instead of `new array();`.
- on the function `error()`, it should be `$connection = $this->connect()`, try not to forget the `$` symbol.